# Are there some documents or examples there about how to change the official caffe files to a fp16 version?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, nvidia-digits

I try to use caffe fp16 on TX1, but many specific layers are not supported by the nvidia current version for [fp16 caffe](https://github.com/NVIDIA/caffe/tree/experimental/fp16). I tried google the internet about how to make the official caffe support half precision, but found nothing about that.